# How to know which value is overlapping in MySQL (using UNIQUE)

Tags: php, mysql

I am using "unique" property of MySQL for username and e-mail column. How can I know which of these two ( username and email) overlapping? I want to echo an error message according to overlapping values. Different error messages for overlapping email and/or username.

Comment: Returning an error message based on database response could be very unreliable. Best thing would be to query for the values you are trying to save and validate it before saving. I guess using some framework to do that for you would be the best approach, try looking for a ORM for PHP.

Comment: I didn't write any specific codes for that. I'm trying to insert users to database. I write some if codes for example; min the lenght of the password, checking if radio buttons selected.. and at the end I add an 'else' to show there is an error and it worked, if ı try to insert a user with a username that already exist in database, it gives me the error masssage which i wrote in the "else". I wonder if there is a way to know which of these two are overlapping.

Comment: Run the query manually in mysql

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are getting an error on an `update` or `insert`.

If you want to specify your own error message, then you need to create a trigger on the table and do the checking yourself.  (Or, alternatively, do all data modifications through a stored procedure where you can do the checking and set error messages in the stored procedure.)  The `signal` syntax allows you to return your own error message from the trigger, so it can contain whatever you like.

You can read more about `signal` [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html).

Comment: fyi, `SIGNAL` is available starting from `5.5`

Answer (score -2):

you could first query the database for that username or email, if you get a result, check the resultset to see which one is the same with the posted value.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM userTable WHERE username = '" . $_POST['username'] . "' OR email = '" . $_POST['email'] . "'
```

if this query returns any results, get the row with mysqli_fetch_assoc and compare username and email values with $_POST values. if it doesn't return any values you can run insert/update query.

Comment: I used to follow this method, this works without marking the columns as unique. But, what is the point to use unique in mysql then? There must be a way to know which are overlapping. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please don't provide SQL with user input in it. That is a very bad practice. Also, the check you've provided is essentially what the DB does with the constraint check.